# Menu not displaying in chrome with polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am new to polymer framework. I am using polymer 2.0.0-rc.3 and latest version of chrome. But below code is not displaying menus.Only "Hello World" is printed in browser. The developer tools console does not show any error.

Below is the code

**test-app.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<!-- Since 'home' is the default route, eagerly load it. -->
<!--  <link rel="import" href="shop-home.html"> -->

<dom-module id="test-app">
  <template>
    <H1>Hello World</H1>
   <paper-toolbar>
      <div class="horizontal-section">
        <paper-menu>
          <paper-item>Inbox</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Starred</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Sent mail</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Drafts</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </div>
     </paper-toolbar>  
   </template>
  <script>
    class testApp extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'test-app'; }
      }

    customElements.define(testApp.is, testApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="import" href="src/test-app.html" async>
</head>
<body>
  <test-app unresolved>test</test-app>

  <script>
    window.performance && performance.mark && performance.mark('index.html');

    Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, dom: 'shadow'};

    (function() {
      if ('registerElement' in document
          && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
          && 'content' in document.createElement('template')) {
        // platform is good!
      } else {
        // polyfill the platform!
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js';
        document.body.appendChild(e);
      }
    })();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**bower.json**

```
"polymer": "polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.3",
"app-layout": "polymerelements/app-layout#^0.10.7",
"app-route": "polymerelements/app-route#^0.9.3",
"iron-flex-layout": "polymerelements/iron-flex-layout#^1.3.2",
"iron-form": "polymerelements/iron-form#^1.1.4",
"iron-icon": "polymerelements/iron-icon#^1.0.12",
"iron-pages": "polymerelements/iron-pages#^1.0.8",
"iron-selector": "polymerelements/iron-selector#^1.5.2",
"paper-icon-button": "polymerelements/paper-icon-button#^1.1.4",
"paper-spinner": "polymerelements/paper-spinner#^1.2.1",
"iron-media-query": "polymerelements/iron-media-query#^1.0.8",
"paper-menu": "polymerelements/paper-menu#^1.2.2",
"paper-item": "polymerelements/paper-item#^1.2.1",
"paper-toolbar": "polymerelements/paper-toolbar#^1.1.7"
```

Does any body have any idea about error? Any guide as how can I debug it to find error?

Comment: most of the elements have an extra branch called "2.0-preview"... you should use those... just add it like "polymerelements/iron-form##2.0-preview" - some elements may not be compatible with polymer 2

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no 2.0-preview branch for paper-menu. Is there any other way to build menu containing menu items in polymer 2.0 as done in bootstrap menu.

Comment: paper-menu seems to be incompatible for now... some seems to have ported it successfully
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/issues/110

Answer (score 0):

`paper-menu` has been deprecated in Polymer 2. As [this comment](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/issues/110#issuecomment-304814891) says:

> This element is deprecated in favor of [paper-listbox](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/polymerelements/paper-listbox), which has been ported already to Polymer 2.0.